# Automating Cassandra setup with Kubernetes, Docker and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, cassandra, autoscaling

My problem statement for 1 click Cassandra Deployment,

1. setup multi-node Cassandra cluster (Autoscaling).
2. Once any changes are made to the cassandra config, it should automatically be deployed to the full cassandra cluster - maybe using Jenkins.
3. this will be on private cloud.

I have setup a single node cassandra cluster under Kubernetes using statefulset.
What I am looking for is some pointers or articles for automating the cassandra setup once any changes are made to the cassandra configs and committed to github or any repository,if that is possible and autoscaling of the cassandra cluster.

Thanks for any suggestions.